# Vuejs. uiv, keep bootstrap popover alive while the popover is being hovered?

Tags: vue.js, popover

I know that there are similar questions with jquery, but this is related to vue.js

I'm using [uiv](https://uiv.wxsm.space/) which is a boostrap version for vue.js. Checking the [docs](https://uiv.wxsm.space/popover/) I'm trying to trigger manually the popover using `trigger="manual"` with a hover event:

```
<popover title="Title" v-model="show">
   <a href="javascript://" @mouseover="show = !show" @mouseleave="show = !show">Toggle Popover</a>
          <template slot="popover">
            <p>Popover content</p>
          </template>
 </popover>
    <script>
      export default {
        data () {
          return {
            show: false
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Well, I understand why the popover is being closed due when I leave the button I set `show` to `false`.

So my question is: **Where do I have to place that `@mouseleave` event in order to prevent closing the popover when it is being hovered?**

Here I have a plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/gTsOJE4k8fQUMcMUpqS6?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem doing this:

```
<popover trigger="hover" title="Title">
    <a href="#" @click.prevent>Toggle Popover</a>
    <template slot="popover">
       <p>Popover content</p>
     </template>
 </popover>
```

Basically, we can use `trigger="hover"` to prevent closing the popover when it is being hovered.

Take a look at this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/RSjhazfxqBhaNqcKijXe?p=preview